# Does your Alma Mater and U.S. News Rankings Really Affect Future Job Opportunities?

Tags: graduate-school, career-path, teaching

I'm in the process of trying to decide on which graduate program to attend.  I am pursuing a Master's level degree in Computer Science in hopes of furthering my web development career.  I would love to be able to teach web development/programming at a community college someday after getting a few more years of industry experience (teaching requires at least a Master's degree).  Previously I taught secondary science before transitioning into web development.

I've been accepted to the following programs:

**Boston University** - Master's in Computer Information Systems / Web Application Development  (U.S. News ranked #51 nationally)

**Brandeis University** - Master's of Software Engineering (U.S. News ranked #31 nationally)

**University of Bridgeport** - Master's of Computer Science (not ranked nationally)

I keep going back and forth in regards to which program I should choose.  University of Bridgeport seems to have a good curriculum and it looks like it will be cheaper (I may get a scholarship), but I'm concerned that it's not viewed as a "top" school.  I would be happy to pay for a more expensive school if it helped provide greater opportunities in the future.

Do you find that going to a "better" school has affected your resume to the point that you may have more teaching opportunities after school?  I realize that a certain school won't earn me the actual position, but having a highly regarded school on my resume MAY lead me to getting more interviews.  Any insights are greatly appreciated.

Thanks and have a good day.

Comment: Are you interested into working later in the US or in other countries?

Answer (score 3):

Here are a few points.

**1. Industry Jobs**

IMHO, "brand" is more important in the industry than in academia. E.g. in general, the HR department is more likely to forward a CV with Harvard on it. Also, people in the industry are probably not able to understand the academic content of your program.

**2. Similar Questions**

[How does the ranking of a university relate to a future career in mathematics?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/3089/how-does-the-ranking-of-a-university-relate-to-a-future-career-in-mathematics?rq=1)

[University rank/stature - How much does it affect one's career post-Ph.D?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/90/university-rank-stature-how-much-does-it-affect-ones-career-post-ph-d?rq=1)

Although these are for PhD programs, there might be interesting bits in there with regards to industry.

**3. Look**

It might be helpful or informative to look at the CVs of the companies or positions you are interested in. This might give you a clue if only the "branded" universities are hired or if there is a wide range of backgrounds. E.g. with regards to mathematics departments, if you look at the CV of professors, a lot of them are Ivy League or MIT, Stanford etc.

Personally, I would pick the most "branded" program I can get into.

Comment: _IMHO, "brand" is more important in the industry than in academia_ - [citation needed]

Comment: @JeffE, It's an opinion, so it doesn't need a citation. However, such a provocative statement certainly begs for some back up.

Comment: I agree with both comment; I should have _some_ evidence. Perhaps something like this would suffice: http://www.usnews.com/education/best-graduate-schools/top-business-schools/articles/2012/05/14/where-the-fortune-500-ceos-went-to-school? There is a table showing that most Fortune 500 CEO went to top schools - not exactly solid evidence but might suggests that industry "likes" brands?

Comment: @Legendre You can find similar evidence for the importance of branding in Academia (see, for instance, [this Academia.SE thread](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/8618/is-it-peculiar-for-a-department-not-to-have-any-of-its-own-phd-graduates-as-prof/8620#8620).